# openerp 7 mod_wsgi trouble with directory match

Tags: apache, apache2, odoo, mod-wsgi, wsgi

im trying to implement Openerp 7 with mod_wsgi at apache2 this is the section in my vhost.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com/web
ServerName example.com
<Directory /var/www/example.com/web>
      Options FollowSymLinks
      AllowOverride All
      Order allow,deny
      Allow from all
</Directory>

WSGIScriptAlias /erp /opt/openerp/server/openerp-wsgi.py
WSGIDaemonProcess openerp user=openerp group=openerp processes=2 python-path=/opt/openerp/server/ display-name=apache-openerp
WSGIProcessGroup openerp

<Directory /opt/openerp/server>
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

but the Apache log alway shows

```
[Tue Mar 04 17:08:48 2014] [error] 2014-03-04 17:08:48,049 32133 INFO bc openerp.modules.loading: Modules loaded.
[Tue Mar 04 18:08:48 2014] [error] [client xxx.xxx.xx.xx] File does not exist: /var/www/example.com/web/web, referer: http://example.com/erp
```

Any suggestions why the wsgi interpreter always points at .../web/web ?

Comment: Likely an absolute URL path is being hardcoded into some page response instead of using any framework mechanism for properly scoping it below the WSGI application entry point, which in this case is '/erp'.

Comment: i think graham's point is right